# Is עליו השלום inappropriate to say about a living person?

Tags: blessing, words, death

The phrase "olov hashalom" is often appended to names of the deceased.  I don't know very much about it's history or any deeper implications, but at face value it just means "peace be upon him."

I once heard someone say "olov hashalom" about a living person, and then vociferously correct themselves with all kinds of blessings for the person to have a long life.  Is there any reason, other than the implication based on its common usage, not to say this about a living person?

Comment: So frustrating- Rabbi Yisroel Reisman in his book on navi, in the back section, asks this very question. if anyone can find it please cite it!

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%203%20Broyde.pdf

Answer (score 6):

In Brachos 64a we find 'when leaving a friend don't say leich bishalom (go in peace) but rather leich lishalom (go for peace) etc, when leaving a dead person don't say leich lishalom, but rather leich bishalom etc'.

Being in a state of shalom is reserved for the dead. 
Hashalom, THE peace, is the epitome of this state of being.

Comment: This is (also?) at the very end of Moed Katan.